# authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

new to asp.net , currently using Session for login/logout

on login page i create a new session

```
          Session["login"]= anyvalue
```

on secure pages

```
 if(session["login"]!=null)
 {
   dostuff();
 }
 else
 Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
```

Is this an OK approach to authentication in asp.net?  Should I be doing anything differently?

**EDIT: Why downvotes ???**
okay guys got it

Comment: asp.net has great stuff already built in such as Forms Authentication.

Comment: I'm confused about what your question is.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Have a look at this article [How To: Use Membership in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)

Comment: I think he wants us to knock up some sort of tutorial, to save him from buying a book or googling for some examples.

Comment: Dude, everyone chill out on the downvotes.  He's new and he's asking a newbie question.  Geeze.  You're punishing people for asking a newbie question.  I understand not upvoting it, but wow, down voting it?

Comment: @granadaCoder: Agree!!! I don't see a point to downvote

Comment: -1, I downvoted because there is no clear question here.  It's nothing personal, just a reflection of the quality of the "question".  If you update with an actual question I will happily reverse my downvote.

Comment: @AbeMiessler simple question, currently using sessions for authentication as i told by a asp.net guy.. but this is not a good approach, i want to do it in a proper way, that's the question, got the answer as ASP.NET membership

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but you still haven't asked a question. I think I understand what you are getting at so I will go ahead and update your question for you. In the future ask a question.

Comment: I have upvoted this question ,as it is a question which every new developer has to face ,and authentication is the most important issue for any application

Comment: A few times in my life, I've been told I'm a little less intransigent than average. ;O

Comment: @Ankit: sure, but when it was first asked it was in pidgin English, full of typos, saying, essentially "i've not done any research whatsoever here, but please tell me what to do". The attitude of all the good developers I've met and worked with has been to do as much research as possible first, then ask concise questions.  It's as much about attitude as experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic "Asp.Net" way of doing this is to use the built-in MembershipProvider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z(v=vs.100).aspx

There is a "baked in" MembershipProvider called the : SqlMembershipProvider

OR

If you already have a data-store with user names and passwords, you would implement a "custom membership provider".

---

Share a little more information, and you can get a little more help.

1. Where are you going to keep your usernames and passwords?
2. If you don't already have this, then please say that.
3. Is this a learning exercise, you're writing a webpage for your kids soccer club, or you're a professional web site (not necessarily asp.net) developer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ASP.NET membership framework. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) (section 7. security).

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work fine, I too was recommended by a senior developer to write
my own logic to authorize access over using the built in security mechanism (that
includes login control)

You might want to add roles in the session as well

And to apply more security, you can store the session in SQL Server